# Tensorflow ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am trying to train an LSTM model using sequences of numbers for a binary classification task.
I don't want to pad the sequences and for this reason I set batch_size = 1. My data looks like this

```
 X_train = [array([-2.03601077, -5.30693448, -4.12608132, -2.83856391, -3.53831573])
 array([-4.15089285, -4.06876003, -4.9501462 ]) array([-2.42697701]) ...
 array([-5.73694178, -3.90681951]) array([-4.0288811])
 array([-2.31485414, -2.71693853])]
```

with a shape of (96306,) and its type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. For example:

```
 X_train[0] = [-2.03601077 -5.30693448 -4.12608132 -2.83856391 -3.53831573]
```

with a shape of (5,) and its class is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

For my labels

```
y_train = [1 0 0 ... 1 1 1]
```

with a shape of (96306,)

Here is the code for training

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Masking
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1,  patience=10)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape = (None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1000, batch_size=1, callbacks=[es])
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I am not entirely sure when it comes from. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code to format the input data(`X_train`, `X_test`) before fitting into the model training:

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).astype('float32')
X_test = np.asarray(X_test).astype('float32')
```